# Is $G$ action on a principal bundle a smooth submersion?

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, principal-bundles

Let  $\pi : P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$ bundle. Suppose $R_{g}: P \rightarrow P$ is a smooth map induced by the smooth right $G$ action on $P$. Is  $ R_{g} $ a smooth submersion for all $g \in G $ ?

Comment: The map $R_g \colon P \to P$ is smooth.  It is bijective with inverse $R_{g^{-1}} \colon P \to P$, and this inverse map $R_{g^{-1}}$ is also smooth.  Therefore ....

Comment: thanks. So it becomes diffeomorphism...